# There are 50 misprints in a book which has 250 pages, find the probability that page 100 has no misprints? (Use theoretically correct distribution)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

My question is where this should be modelled as a binomial distribution problem or a Poisson distribution problem.

Any hint/advice helps, thanks in advance!

Comment: Think it through. Assuming that a given misprint has an equal chance of appearing on any page, what can you tell me?

Comment: @Joe if it's an equal chance of appearing anywhere then it should probably be 1/5 even for page 100?

Comment: isnt it $\frac 1 {250} \cdot (1-\frac {50}{250})$?

Comment: @NikhilGopal Let's focus on one single error before we generalize. If there were only one misprint in the book, and it has an equal chance of appearing on any page, what can you tell me?

Comment: @Joe that it has a 1 in 250 chance of being on the 100th page?

Comment: @NikhilGopal Exactly right! Now if we have $n=50$ errors, each with an equal chance of appearing on any page *independent of one another*, what can you tell me?

Comment: @Joe that every page has a 50/250 chance of having an error, including the 100th page?

Comment: @NikhilGopal Not quite. You have assumed that exactly 50 pages have misprints, when in reality there could be multiple misprints on the same page. Suppose that each error independently has a $1/250$ chance of being on page 100. What can you tell me? Does this remind you of any specific distribution?

Comment: @Joe Ah alright.. I wanna say Poisson?

Comment: @NikhilGopal No not a Poisson. A Poisson distribution would make sense if any number of errors could occur. In this case, we know that exactly 50 errors occurred. Suppose that we considered the placement of each error to be an independent trial. A trial is a success if the error is not on page 100, and a failure if the error is on page 100. Doesn't this sound like a binomial distribution?

Comment: @Joe it does! But I'm not quite sure about how to model the solution.

Comment: @NikhilGopal Can you tell me what the probability mass function is for a binomial distribution would be with the correct parameters?

Comment: @Joe nCx . P^x . Q^(n-x) where n is the lot size, p is the fraction under consideration; forgive me for my formatting I'm on mobile rn

Comment: @NikhilGopal That's exactly right. Can you tell me what $n$ and $p$ would be in this question?

Comment: @Joe n = 250 and p =50/250

Comment: @NikhilGopal Not quite. Think of each misprint as a trial, and call the trial a success if it isn't on page 100. Now can you tell me what $n$ and $p$ are?

Comment: @Joe if each misprint is a trial then n would be 50? And p would be 1- 1/250?

Comment: @NikhilGopal Exactly right! $n = 50$ and $p = 249/250$. Now what is the probability of 50 successful trials? That is, what is the probability that none of the errors occur on page 100? You can directly use the formula you gave me before.

Comment: @Joe Thank you so much for walking me through this! Much appreciated. 

Comment: @NikhilGopal No problem. You should also look at David G. Stork's answer. While I disagree with him about the Poisson distribution being more appropriate for this specific problem, he is right that it would be better for modelling errors in books coming from a real-world manufacturing process. It would be worth your time to understand both answers.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on whether what perspective we take on the problem:

**Case 1: Binomial - We know upfront that there are 50 misprints.**

Since multiple errors can appear on the same page, we can first count the number of ways the misprints can be placed using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

This gives us $299\choose50$ for the total number of ways for the misprints to be distributed. To count the number of ways where page 100 has no misprints, we assume the book has 249 pages, giving us $298\choose50$. So, our answer is $$\frac{298\choose50}{299\choose50}=\frac{249}{299}\sim\color{red}{0.8238}$$

**Case 2: Poisson - The misprints happened randomly, but it just so happened that there were 50 of them**

In this case, we consider each misprint as an independent event, and consider the probability of it not occurring on a given page.

This gives us $$\bigg(\frac{249}{250}\bigg)^{50}\sim\color{red}{0.8184}$$

Comment: The binomial distribution is appropriate *only* if we know *for certain* that there must be $50$ typos somehow sprinkled through each book.  If instead typos are random processes with an unknown rate and for this particular book there happen to be $50$ typos, then a binomial distribution is correct.  I think the latter interpretation is far more realistic and that the Poisson should be used.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork satisfied?

Comment: @Yes, In the ***Case 2*** you get the same result I did.  The problem statement is, frankly, a bit odd.  Presumably whoever found that there were exactly $50$ typos in the book *knew* exactly how many were on page $100$, but declined to tell anyone.  I would have avoided the ambiguity by stating that errors are truly random (throughout all books), i.e., per page, of initially unknown rate, that someone estimated that rate on *other* books to be $\mu = 1/5$, and that a fresh book is picked up, and examined on page $100$.  Seems principled (and interesting).  But your two cases cover all.

Answer (score 1):

If we assign each misprint a value then
P(100 does not have the $n^{th}$ misprint) $= \frac {249}{250} $

Since each event is independent,

P(100 does not have any misprint) $=(\frac {249}{250})^{50} = 0.81840245067$